# Bottom divider is missing when visibility of the last view is set to GONE in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have simple LinearLayout with 2 buttons. View looks ok, middle and end dividers are shown. When I set programatically visibility of second button to View.GONE the divider below first button is missing. How to change it?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle|end"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/1_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/big_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/big_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/2_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/big_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/big_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is part of the bigger view so it is hard to make a screenshot. The point is that I suppose that the divider at the of the Linear Layout should be always visible, not matter how many buttons are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in `LinearLayout` implementation as it should set the `end` divider for button with `1_id` id after `2_id` button is gone. However this is not the case here so a possible workaround would be to leave out the `end` divider setting from `LinearLayout` and add a dummy `View` at the end so it's middle divider will simulate the last divider.

Look at this example:

```
<!-- No 'end' divider in 'android:showDividers' attribute -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="Line 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Line 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Last line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Dummy view to simulate last divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by doing a copy of the support library class LinearLayoutCompat and modifying the two following methods:

```
void drawDividersVertical(Canvas canvas) {
    final int count = getVirtualChildCount();
    View lastVisibleChild = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getVirtualChildAt(i);
        if (child != null && child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            lastVisibleChild = child;
            if (hasDividerBeforeChildAt(i)) {
                final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                final int top = child.getTop() - lp.topMargin - mDividerHeight;
                drawHorizontalDivider(canvas, top);
            }
        }
    }

    if (hasDividerBeforeChildAt(count)) {
        final View child = lastVisibleChild;
        int bottom = 0;
        if (child == null) {
            bottom = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - mDividerHeight;
        } else {
            final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            bottom = child.getBottom() + lp.bottomMargin;
        }
        drawHorizontalDivider(canvas, bottom);
    }
}

protected boolean hasDividerBeforeChildAt(int childIndex) {
    if (childIndex == 0) {
        return (mShowDividers & SHOW_DIVIDER_BEGINNING) != 0;
    } else if (childIndex == getChildCount()) {
        return (mShowDividers & SHOW_DIVIDER_END) != 0;
    } else if ((mShowDividers & SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE) != 0) {
        boolean hasVisibleViewBefore = false;
        for (int i = childIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (getChildAt(i).getVisibility() != GONE) {
                hasVisibleViewBefore = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return hasVisibleViewBefore || (mShowDividers & SHOW_DIVIDER_BEGINNING) != 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200396&thanks=200396&ts=1454685515